# After ubuntu 19.04 update, sound card cannot be detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, alsa

I have used software update. After then there's no sound.
After spending hours reading similar problems I realize that none of them (including reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio) works for me.

Using

```
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

I get the following results:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cannon Lake PCH
 cAVS   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11  Memory at
 a4430000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]     Memory at a4100000
 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]   Capabilities: <access denied>

 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev
 10)
 -- 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f8 (rev a1)   Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3fff     Flags: bus
 master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10     Memory at a4080000 (32-bit,
 non-prefetchable) [size=16K]   Capabilities: <access denied>

 01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad8 (rev a1)
 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device
 3fff
```

It seems that despite the sound card does exits, the system cannot installing a proper driver. Following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
I tried to instally snd-hda-intel driver but it returns:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-29-generic
```

I then visit https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages
but I don't know how to install the proper .tar.gz as a driver (possibly for oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201907080246~ubuntu19.04.1.tar.gz  ?)
Can someone help me to work it out? Thanks!

**Update1**
`dkms status` returns nothing. Tried `sudo apt update` and `upgrade` does not solve the problem.

Here is what

```
lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
```

returns:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [1462:cb50]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [1462:7b50]
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10f8] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3fff]
01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1ad8] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3fff]
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again. Maybe kernel modules didn't install properly. Also add output of `dkms status` to your question. Please format code using `{}` button.

Comment: And also add `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`

Comment: You need to install kernel modules package for You kernel version `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-29-generic`.

Answer (score 2):

found this  solution here https://superuser.com/a/1509313/1151609

it worked for me

Here is a copy of the original post from [hopeseekr](https://superuser.com/users/48215/hopeseekr)

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
Find GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and add snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 to the end 
of it. (ex: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 
snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0")
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Reboot the system.
```

Comment: Same happened to me, Same solution worked for me