# HP Omen 17t - Ubuntu 20.04 - No Sound

Tags: sound, hp

I have a brand new HP Omen 17t laptop.  I loaded Ubuntu 20.04 and have no sound.  I have tried the steps recommended here:

- [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook)
- [No sound on arm ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230407/no-sound-on-arm-ubuntu-20-04)

Any pointers someone here can offer would be appreciated.  For reference, I have included the output of lshw below.

```
H/W path           Device   Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         OMEN by HP Laptop 17-cb0xxx (5VX36AV)
/0                          bus            8603
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/10                       memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/10/0                     memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/10/1                     memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/1a                       memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/1b                       memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/1c                       memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/1d                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/100                      bridge         8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                  display        TU104BM [GeForce RTX 2080 Mobile]
/0/100/1/0.1                multimedia     TU104 HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1/0.2                bus            TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller
/0/100/1/0.2/0     usb3     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1/0.2/1     usb4     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1/0.3                bus            TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
/0/100/8                    generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
/0/100/12                   generic        Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
/0/100/14                   bus            Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0        usb1     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1               input          Gaming Mouse G502
/0/100/14/0/5               multimedia     HP Wide Vision HD Camera
/0/100/14/0/e               communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/1        usb2     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                 memory         RAM memory
/0/100/15                   bus            Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                 bus            Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                   communication  Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
/0/100/17                   storage        82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
/0/100/1b                   bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17
/0/100/1b/0                 bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/0               bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/0/0             generic        JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/1               bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2               bridge         JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2/0             bus            JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/0  usb5     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1  usb6     bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d                   bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0                 storage        E12 NVMe Controller
/0/100/1d.5                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14
/0/100/1d.5/0      enp60s0  network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d.6                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15
/0/100/1d.6/0               generic        GL9750 SD Host Controller
/0/100/1d.7                 bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #16
/0/100/1d.7/0      wlp62s0  network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1f                   bridge         HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                 bus            Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
/0/1                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                        generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/4                        generic        PnP device HPQ8001
/0/5                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                        system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                          power          SR04070
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501

Comment: Possible because they have the same sound card:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175052/after-ubuntu-19-04-update-sound-card-cannot-be-detected  Except for the answer after making the changes all you should have to run is `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook)

Comment: @dlin - sorry no, the article did not help.  I had found it before I posted my own question.  In my case, the real key to the solution was the snd-hda-intel driver.  I am not 100% sure, but I believe it was failing to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 11.05.20**

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 today.  I did not have to apply the changes noted below.  I did not have any sound or video problems.  It all just worked.  Since the install may not work for everyone out of the box, I will leave the original answer that worked for me below.  As always, hope this answer helps someone.

**Original Answer Follows:**

@Raffa and @Terrance - +1 to you both.  Your comments helped to point me in the right direction.

OK, so I have it working now, and here is how I got there. I tried updating grub as suggested in this post:

- [After ubuntu 19.04 update, sound card cannot be detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175052/after-ubuntu-19-04-update-sound-card-cannot-be-detected)

It borked my video though.  Screen would go blank on login, and never return.    It lead me to do some additional searching on snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect, and I found the following article:

- https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Way at the bottom of the article it has the following:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And then add the following line to it.

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

It's now working 100% for me.  All of my hardware recognized and tip-top.  I hope this helps someone; thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if I underestimate you, but have you confirmed that your user belongs to the group audio?

```
groups youruser
```

If not you can add it with

```
sudo adduser youruser audio
```

Comment: Good question, and it may help someone else.  In my case, Ubuntu 20.04.1 installs and the sound works perfectly right out of the box.  I updated the answer with additional notes regarding Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

Sound card not recognized. My solution.
I upgraded from 18.04 within the installed OS to 20.04 and had no sound. "Dummy Output". I tried every solution I could fine with no luck. I finally decided to do a fresh install from a Newly made Live USB. Made sure the speakers were turned on during install just in case it made sound card more visible. After new install everything works. I had no luck try do a reinstall either. Best advice download a fresh ISO and make a Live USB.