# Ubuntu 20.04 - HP OMEN 2019 - No Sound

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, soundcard

My kernel version is 5.4.0-40

Here is my `lspci` output for audio device:

```
Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

I tried to reinstall nvidia driver but it didn't work what can I do else

Here is PaVuControl screenshot:

[image: here is PaVuControl screenshot]

Comment: Please specify what version of Ubuntu you are on. 18.04 for example. Install pulseaudio volume control and see if you have any input devices capturing sound and any output devices.  Play a video or audio and watch and see if anything is sending sound.

Comment: There is no sound at all

Comment: Have you install PaVuControl? And it does not see anything coming or going.

Comment: Have you seen the solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/1231693/612 ?

Comment: @popey I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to re install base apps with these command. `apt install --reinstall alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui`

Comment: I wrote a tutorial to get everything, including sound, working smoothly on the Omen 15. It's for Manjaro KDE, but you might find it useful for your sound issues on Ubuntu too. https://medium.com/@claudio.cambra/troubleshooting-manjaro-linux-on-your-2019-hp-omen-15-gaming-laptop-august-2020-c570ced15ca8