# Does ubuntu 22 works fine with OMEN 17 with RTX 4080 and intel i9?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, python3, gpu-driver

Currently looking for buying a new laptop, which can run ubuntu 22 desktop successfully. I've tried with Macbook pro 14 with M2, it may not support ubuntu for next upcoming 5 years at least. So in comparison to those specs. I'm looking to this laptop. HP OMEN 17 (2023) with i9 and RTX 4080, Now looking for the answer, will it support ubuntu 22 desktop. My main intentions are to leverage cpu and gpu fully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Comment: Hardware shopping recommendations are off topic at Ask Ubuntu, however the HP Omen 17t supports Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231653/hp-omen-17t-ubuntu-20-04-no-sound