# Microphone not being recognised by Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, microphone, audio-recording

I am using Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
My microphone is not being recognized by the OS.
If I try to record something, its just random noise.
Microphone worked nicely with good quality audio in Windows on the same computer.

[onlinemictest.com](https://onlinemictest.com) doesn't even recognize input from mic of headphones.

Windows used `Intel Microphone Array` for sound input.

In Ubuntu, Device for sound input shows: `Internal Microphone- Built-in Audio`

The output of `sudo lshw -class multimedia` is:

```
*-multimedia              
   description: Audio device
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:a3080000-a3083fff
*-usb:0
   description: Video
   product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
   vendor: CNFHH46P3354200FE7C0
   physical id: 5
   bus info: usb@1:5
   version: 85.11
   serial: 200901010001
   capabilities: usb-2.01
   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-multimedia
   description: Multimedia audio controller
   product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
   resources: irq:130 memory:a54a0000-a54a3fff memory:a5200000-a52fffff
```

Comment: Which Audio device to you have? Open System Settings and check Input section. Please post also the output of this command:`sudo lshw -class multimedia`

Comment: @koni_raidI have added the details in the question. Please help.

Comment: have a look at this: (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175052/after-ubuntu-19-04-update-sound-card-cannot-be-detected)

Comment: @koni_raid I have done that already. To no results.