# I have installed Ubuntu and found that I have no sound

Tags: sound, codecs

here is output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a308 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
```

So, I have two systems on my HDD: OpenSUSE and Ubuntu, after Ubuntu installation I have no sound in both systems, and they have the same errors. How can I fix sound? Also, I use EFI.

[image]

More info:

```
Module #0
    Name: module-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #1
    Name: module-stream-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #2
    Name: module-card-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #3
    Name: module-augment-properties
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #4
    Name: module-switch-on-port-available
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "David Henningsson"
        module.description = "Switches ports and profiles when devices are plugged/unplugged"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #5
    Name: module-switch-on-connect
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Michael Terry"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is added, switch to it or conditionally switch to it"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #6
    Name: module-udev-detect
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #8
    Name: module-bluetooth-policy
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau, Pali Rohár"
        module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #9
    Name: module-bluetooth-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #10
    Name: module-bluez5-discover
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #11
    Name: module-native-protocol-unix
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #12
    Name: module-default-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #13
    Name: module-always-sink
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #14
    Name: module-null-sink
    Argument: sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Clocked NULL sink"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #15
    Name: module-intended-roles
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #16
    Name: module-suspend-on-idle
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #17
    Name: module-console-kit
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each ConsoleKit session of this user"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #18
    Name: module-systemd-login
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #19
    Name: module-position-event-sounds
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #20
    Name: module-role-cork
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Mute & cork streams with certain roles while others exist"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #21
    Name: module-snap-policy
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Canonical Ltd"
        module.description = "Ubuntu Snap policy management"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #22
    Name: module-filter-heuristics
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #23
    Name: module-filter-apply
    Argument: 
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #24
    Name: module-x11-publish
    Argument: display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 credential publisher"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #25
    Name: module-x11-cork-request
    Argument: display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Synthesize X11 media key events when cork/uncork is requested"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Module #26
    Name: module-x11-xsmp
    Argument: display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority session_manager=local/linux:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1506,unix/linux:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1506
    Usage counter: n/a
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 session management"
        module.version = "13.99.1"

Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: auto_null
    Description: Dummy Output
    Driver: module-null-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 14
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: auto_null.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Dummy Output
    Driver: module-null-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 14
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: auto_null
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    Formats:
        pcm

Client #0
    Driver: module-systemd-login.c
    Owner Module: 18
    Properties:
        application.name = "Login Session 2"
        systemd-login.session = "2"

Client #4
    Driver: module-x11-xsmp.c
    Owner Module: 26
    Properties:
        application.name = "XSMP Session on gnome-session as 1023d146495a173160956504714546600000015060060"
        xsmp.vendor = "gnome-session"
        xsmp.client.id = "1023d146495a173160956504714546600000015060060"

Client #5
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Shell Volume Control"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "3.36.4"
        application.process.id = "1525"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #6
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Media Keys"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = ""
        application.process.id = "1675"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gsd-media-keys"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #7
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "org.gnome.Shell.Extensions"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "1834"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gjs-console"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #10
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "Mutter"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "1525"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #11
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "Firefox"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "1980"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"

Client #12
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "Firefox"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"
        application.version = "84.0"
        application.process.id = "1980"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #22
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "Terminal"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.icon_name = "org.gnome.Terminal"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "3245"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-terminal-server"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Client #25
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 11
    Properties:
        application.name = "pactl"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "3387"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "pactl"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"

Sample #0
    Name: bell-window-system
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Volume: (invalid)
            balance 0,00
    Duration: 0,3s
    Size: 49,9 KiB
    Lazy: no
    Filename: n/a
    Properties:
        media.role = "event"
        event.description = "Bell event"
        event.id = "bell-window-system"
        media.name = "bell-window-system"
        media.filename = "/usr/share//sounds/Yaru/stereo/bell.oga"
        application.name = "Mutter"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "1525"
        application.process.user = "iam"
        application.process.host = "linux"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "d58fcf10d2034b5ea2065f84708ec927"
```

And the text of error from logs:

```
Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```

Output of lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [17aa:313d]
```

Comment: If the problem persists among multiple operating systems, it's probably a hardware issue. Check your ports, cables, and sound equipment.

Comment: Do you share your HOME with the distributions?

Comment: Unix & Linux has a Q&A for sharing /home between OpenSuse and Ubuntu: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/different-linux-distros-sharing-the-same-home-folder

Comment: @Nmath so, I think this is not hardware just because I can see my comments through terminal.

Comment: How is that related to the sound problem?

Comment: @Takkat Ubuntu and Opensuse has its own home and root partitions

Comment: @Takkat Well, I have onced fired up my video card, when it happened I was unable to see it in terminal with any commands, in this case I can see my sound card

Comment: See if you can get a more detailed information on the state of sound card with `pactl list`. If in doubt [edit] the relevant section into your question. Use text rather than a terminal screenshot for better readability.

Comment: @Takkat I added info

Comment: @IgorFoxly ALSA can not detect you sound card (check with `aplay -l`), This may come from [bug #186406](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061) or your card may not (yet) be supported by ALSA. Sometimes an older kernel may work better. To see if this was the case try booting a live system ("try out Ubuntu") e.g from 20.04 or 18.04. Also you may try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175052/after-ubuntu-19-04-update-sound-card-cannot-be-detected

Comment: @Takkat thanks for link but unfortunately I dont have a sound even from usd stick