# Audio device not working on fresh installation Ubuntu 22.04, Leptop Model: OMEN by HP 16.1 inch Gaming Laptop 16-k0000 (594K2AV)

Tags: nvidia, pulseaudio, hp, intel, realtek

I did the fresh ubuntu 22.04 installation on OMEN by HP 16.1 inch Gaming Laptop 16-k0000 (594K2AV) laptop.

And I found that the Audio is not working, 3.5 mm jack is also not working.

I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as well, but getting the same issue.

Kindly provide the best solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

First, try running  `$ pulseaudio --start` ,this should enable sound. If not:

Test the current situation with default output.

```
$ speaker-test
```

See other available sound outputs.

```
$ aplay -l
```

Pick other outputs then try them.

```
$ speaker-test -D hw:<card id>,<device id>
```

For example, if the output of aplay contains a line

```
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
```

Then the command to try this output will be

```
$ speaker-test -D hw:1,7
```

Kill all pulse audio daemons to prevent them from interfering during the troubleshooting.

`$ mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse_old`  # Remove potentially corrupted pulse files

```
$ sudo killall pulseaudio
```

Try step 1, 2, and 3 again.

Check dmesg and journalctl to see if any errors regarding the sound are reported.

This link may also be of use: [After ubuntu 19.04 update, sound card cannot be detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175052/after-ubuntu-19-04-update-sound-card-cannot-be-detected)

Comment: I tried `speaker-test -D hw:<card id>,<device id>` with multiple options, It didn't work.

Comment: ankitgoswami@OMEN-Gaming-16:~$  speaker-test -D hw:0,7
`
speaker-test 1.2.6

Playback device is hw:0,7
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Channels count (1) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
`